# Is a Swift String constant of a different type than a String literal?

Tags: string, swift, types, constants, literals

In Swift 2.1 the snippet below generates an error.

```
var str = "Hello, playground!"

// Success Case
if "!" == str.characters.last {
    print("Tone it down please")
}

// Fail Case
let bang = "!"

if bang == str.characters.last {  // this line won't compile
    print("Tone it down please")
}
```

The compiler error says:

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String'
>   and '_Element?'

So what is the recommended way to use a *constant* as opposed to a *literal* in this situation?  (I'm learning Swift, so please feel free to mention if there's a Swift-er way to handle this kind of comparison check.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your "Fail case", this is because `str.characters.last` is an Optional and is a `Character`, but `bang` is a `String`.

You can safely unwrap and compare with `if let ... where`, and use `String()` to change the `Character` to a `String` for the comparison:

```
if let last = str.characters.last where String(last) == bang {
    print("Tone it down please")
}
```

Comment: The relevant [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID298) doesn't talk about it (or maybe I didn't find it), but I wouldn't be surprised if your "Success case" worked because Swift automatically aliases `"!"` as a `Character` when using the `==` operator between a *single character String* and a *Character*; and this mechanism doesn't work with `bang` because it's not a literal. But this is just a guess, so I didn't include it in my answer.

Comment: I think your "guess" is correct. "!" can be both a String literal (the default) and a Character literal (when inferred from the context). `let bang = Character("!")` makes the "Fail Case" compile. – So this problem is actually *unrelated* to Optionals. `let bang = "!" ; if bang == str.characters.last! { }` does not compile either.

Comment: Thanks!  Alternatively, I discovered I could also say: `let bang = "!".characters.last`

Comment: Great point about the issue having nothing to do with _optionals_!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, the first operator is a `String`, and the second one is an optional `Character`.

But you've already demonstrated that you know how to turn a string into an `Character?`, so lets use that:

```
if bang.characters.last == str.characters.last {
    print("Tone it down please")
}
```

You know that `bang.characters.last` will just return `"!"`, but now it will be of the same type as `str.characters.last`, so it will be trivial to compare them.

Comment: The error doesn't actually say the second is an optional `Character`.  It says it is an optional `_Element`, which is not something I recognize.  But I take your point about converting from a string to the last character.  Thanks.  (See the variation posted in my comment for the preceding answer for another place to locate the conversion to character.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the good discussion. Here's my own answer to improve the illustration by eliminating extraneous optionals, and to demonstrate both the ***good and the bad*** of type inference at play:

```
let a:String = "!"              // type is String
let b:Character = "!"           // type is Character
let c = "!".characters.last!    // type is _Element
let bang = "!"                  // inferred type is String

if "!" == a { print("literal matches string") }
if "!" == b { print("literal matches Character") }
if "!" == c { print("literal matches _Element") }

if a == b { print("a matches b") }      // Err: 'String' to 'Character'
if a == c { print("a matches c") }      // Err: 'String' to '_Element' 
if b == c { print("b matches c") }      // OK: 'Character' to '_Element'
```

Conclusion:  A literal consisting of a single quoted character can be recognized as a `String` or as a `Character` (or equivalently an `_Element`), if the context suggests it.

Importantly: *The type of a constant is permanently established when it is declared. The type of a literal is inferred from its context, so the same literal may have different types in different contexts.*

**Flexible type inference afforded to a literal is not available with a constant.**

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is totally related, but I found this post as I had problems converting between `characters.first`, `characters.last` and `Int`.

In case this helps anyone:

```
let element = characters.first! // the ! is important
let myString = String(element) 
let myInt = Int(myString) // may be nil if character is not an int
```